# Consulta SQL para sistema de mensagem

Tags: php, mysql, query, chat

Estou a modelar uma base para troca de mensagens entre usuários, sendo que tenho as seguintes tabelas, `user`, `user_friend` e `user_friend_message`.
A tabela `user` guarda todos os usuários do sistema, `user_friend` faz a ligação de amizade entre dois usuários e por fim `user_friend_message` que guarda a troca de mensagens entre dois usuários.

Na ligação de amizade na tabela `user_friend` tenho as colunas `id_user` e `id_friend`, o usuário que envia o convite tem o id armazenado na coluna `id_user` e seu amigo na `id_friend` e vice versa.

O meu problema consiste em uma tela que lista todos os contatos/amigos sendo que a ordem de exibição deve ser primeiro contatos com mensagens enviadas não lidas e depois usuários com mensagens lidas ou sem mensagens.

A troca de mensagens segue a mesma lógica da ligação de amizade. O usuário que envia a mensagem tem o ID armazenado na coluna `id_user` e o que recebe na `id_friend`. As mensagens entre dois usuário sempre serão exibidas na mesma tela(estilo chat do facebook, hangout etc..) e independe se o usuário enviou ou recebeu a mensagem (`id_user` ou `id_friend`)

A modelagem está muito confusa pra mim e não sei se consigo fazer isso com apenas uma query. A query abaixo faz consulta de toda ligação de amizade do usuário e ordena em ordem decrescente pela data de envio da mensagem, porém não me retorna o resultado que preciso.

```
SELECT 
   u.id 
FROM 
  `users_friends` uf  
INNER JOIN 
   `users` u ON u.id = uf.id_user
LEFT JOIN 
   `users_friend_message` m ON m.id = m.id_user
WHERE 
   (uf.id_friend = :id_user OR uf.id_user = :id_user) AND uf.status = 1 
ORDER BY 
   m.date_send DESC
```

Comment: Você vai ter que adicionar uma nova coluna na tabela `user_friend_message` que será responsável por dizer se a mensagem já foi lida ou não. Para fazer estilo o chat do Facebook, você pode implementar um script JS que irá detectar cliques na janela de conversação e, caso houvesse mensagens não lidas, irá enviar um update via AJAX pra marcar a mensagem como lida.

Comment: O problema não é em marcar a mensagem como lida ou não lida e sim montar uma query que liste todos o contatos de um usuário mesmo que eles já tenham conversas ou não. Caso tenha conversas não lida o usuário ficará no topo dos contatos por ordem de mensagem enviada. Citei facebook para entender mais ou menos como preciso que a tela seja exibida. No meu caso a conversa não será atualizada em tempo real, na verdade parece mais com um leitor de e-mails com a diferença de ter que listar todos os contatos(com conversa ou não)